# Can't pass html tag into title property

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to pass the in the `title` property the html tag like this:

```
var unavailablePeriod = 
{
    'title': EALang['unavailable'] + ' <br><small>' + ((val[i]['notes'].length > 30) ? val[i].substring(0, 30) + '...' : val[i['notes']) + '</small>',
    'start': Date.parse(val[i]['start_datetime']),
    'end': Date.parse(val[i]['end_datetime']),
    'allDay': false,
    'color': '#879DB4',
    'editable': true,
    'className': 'fc-unavailable fc-custom',
    'data':  val[i],
    'column' : column_operator
};
$calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', unavailablePeriod, false);
```

But in the visualization is displayed this:

[image]

I'm using the version 2.3.1 of FullCalendar, but in the past with the 1.6.1 all working perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Untrusted html inserted to the document can run arbitrary scripts. It seems fullcalendar protects you by inserting it as text, not html. There might be some option to insert it as html, but then make sure `val` is trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They changed it so that HTML in `event.title` is escaped. You can try injecting HTML through [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/):

```
var unavailablePeriod = 
{
    'title': EALang['unavailable'] + ' ' + ((val[i]['notes'].length > 30) ? val[i].substring(0, 30) + '...' : val[i['notes']),
    'titleHTML': EALang['unavailable'] + ' <br><small>' + ((val[i]['notes'].length > 30) ? val[i].substring(0, 30) + '...' : val[i['notes']) + '</small>',
    ...
};
```

And then:

```
eventRender: function(event, el) {
    el.find('.fc-title').html(event.titleHTML);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zoogttrs/)

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle please?

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand el what's rapresent. I want call this function to another class.